# DAX How to Get a Row Number Value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visualization in Power BI.

I am trying to get a row number added for my table.

I am using the following DAX: `RANKX(table_1,table_1[customerSK],,ASC,DENSE)`

I am getting the following error message:

> A single value for column CustomerSK in table_1 cannot be determined.
> This happens when a measure formula refers to a column that contains
> many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max,
> count...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DAX formula in a calculated column instead of in a measure.

Comment: In my source table, there are duplicate values. It almost seems as I need to create a table of distinct combinations and then use a calculated column, now I just need to figure out how to keep my current filters in place.

Comment: Using index column gives row numbers